# c# Web Server - How to send images

Tags: c#, html, image, server, hosting

I'm creating a server using C# and I'm able to receive requests and return HTML, but I'm not sure what I have to do to send image files so they will display on the page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace Ambar
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(80);
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("waiting for a connection");
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                Console.WriteLine(client.GetStream().ToString());

                try
                {
                    string request = sr.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine(request);
                    string[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
                    string page = tokens[1];
                    if (page == "/")
                    {
                        page = "/default.htm";
                    }
                    StreamReader file = new StreamReader("../../web" + page);
                    sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n");

                    string data = file.ReadLine();
                    while (data != null)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(data);
                        sw.Flush();
                        data = file.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 404 OK\n");
                    sw.WriteLine("<H1> Future Site of Ambar Remake </H!>");
                    sw.Flush();
                }

                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm able to host whatever HTML I want, but if I try to display an image like

`<img src="picture.gif" alt="a picture" height="42" width="42">`

I'm not sure how to host that image and have it displayed there.

Comment: Did you tried to send image in binary format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP request and response header have two line breaks(\n) to divide Header part and content part.

for example:
(**Request** that requesting an image(image.gif) from server)

```
GET /image.gif HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: WebBrowser
Accept-Encoding: deflate,gzip
Connection: keep-alive
... and more headers if present ...
```

(**Response** for image request)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: <Length_Of_Content>
Content-Type: image/gif
... and more headers if present ...

<Data_Of_Image>
```

As you can see, there's two line breaks(\n) between *response header* and *contents*.
So, you have to read files as byte array(`byte[]`). In this situation, you can easily read files using `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(string)`.

Now, one more left. I told you read files as *byte array*, but there's no way to join `string` and `byte[]`. So you have to encode string to byte[] and join header bytes and content bytes.
+ We can't send byte array via `StreamWriter` so, we'll use `NetworkStream`.

Here's explanation:

```
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

...

string[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
string page = tokens[1];
if (page == "/")
{
    page = "/default.htm";
}
//StreamReader file = new StreamReader("../../web" + page);
byte[] file = null;

try { file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"../../web" + page); }

// In this 'catch' block, you can't read requested file.
catch {
    // do something (like printing error message)
}

// We are not going to use StreamWriter, we'll use StringBuilder
StringBuilder sbHeader = new StringBuilder();

// STATUS CODE
sbHeader.AppendLine("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

// CONTENT-LENGTH
sbHeader.AppendLine("Content-Length: " + file.Length);

// Append one more line breaks to seperate header and content.
sbHeader.AppendLine();

// List for join two byte arrays.
List<byte> response = new List<byte>();

// First, add header.
response.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sbHeader.ToString()));

// Last, add content.
response.AddRange(file);

// Make byte array from List<byte>
byte[] responseByte = response.ToArray();

// Send entire response via NetworkStream
ns.Write(responseByte, 0, responseByte.Length);
```

This is it. I hope you can understand my bad english :O.
Hope this help to you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using web sockets.

You'll need to return the image as a base 64 encoded string, then use the

```
<img src ="data:image/png;base64," + base64ImageHere
```

Format